# Mesh Boundary Option Sculpting

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation, sculpt-mode, brushes

I’ve never had luck getting the mesh boundary option to work as seen in these GIFs. Turning it on/off under advanced brush settings has no discernible effect, even when increasing propogation steps. I’ve tried activating it with Alt-A to load the pie menu - and there are inconsistencies between the pie menu and the properties panel about if its even activated or not also seen in the GIF. Any ideas on how I can get the Mesh Boundary option to perform like how it does in Pablos videos? - In particular - I want to be able to sculpt on the interior of the mesh without it affecting the margins. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: About the inconsistency: I didn't know the [Auto-Masking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/controls.html) (Viewport header > dropdown menu or Alt+A > pie menu) but this is not the same as the [auto-masking in the brush settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/brush_settings.html#sculpt-tool-settings-brush-settings-advanced) (Tool Settings > Advanced). The first options are global, the second are brush-dependent. Both *Mesh Boundary* options work for me with the *Cloth* brush (Drag, Radial) and the *Deformation* brush in Blender 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I played with it more - I realize now the issues were showing up after using remesh modifier on the plane, which makes it double sided. My understanding is that this makes the plane incompatible with mesh boundary - mesh boundary only works on single sided meshes. Using SubD modifier keeps it a single plane and mesh boundary works, Thanks,